# Passing page URL parameter to controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, url, controller, routes, laravel-5

In my application I have a page it called `index.blade`, with route `/index`. In its URL, it has some `get` parameter like `?order` and `?type`.

I want to pass these `$_get` parameter to my route controller action, query from DB and pass its result data to the index page. What should I do?

Comment: Please tell us what solution you have tried and share it

Comment: @Abbasi the solution is under this comment :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to access the data sent from `get` or `post` request use

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = $request->input('order');
    $type = $request->input('type');
    return view('whatever')->with('order', $order)->with('type', $type);
}
```

you can also use wildcards.

**Exemple link**

```php
website.dev/user/potato
```

**Route**

```php
Route::put('user/{name}', 'UserController@show');
```

**Controller**

```php
public function update($name)
{
    User::where('name', $name)->first();
    return view('test')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Check the Laravel Docs [**Requests**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests).

Answer (score 3):

For those who need to pass part of a url as a parameter (tested in laravel 6.x, maybe it works on laravel 5.x):

**Route**

```
Route::get('foo/{bar}', 'FooController@getFoo')->where('bar', '(.*)');
```

**Controller:**

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function getFoo($url){
    return $url;
    }
}
```

Test 1:

`localhost/api/foo/path1/path2/file.gif` will send to controller and return:

```
path1/path2/file.gif
```

Test 2:

`localhost/api/foo/path1/path2/path3/file.doc` will send to controller and return:

```
path1/path2/path3/file.doc
```

and so on...