# Laravel get the parameter of url in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a value of the parameter in to a variable this is what I have so far:

```
public function getname(Request $request)
{
    echo ($request->input('id'));

    return view('test.test1');
}
```

and my route is:

```
Route::get('/test/{id}','Controller@getname');
```

the output I get is `NULL`
how can I get the value of the url parameter?

my url is:

```
localhost/test/test1/4
```

so I want 4 to be outputed.

I tried doing thr request method but didn't work so it's not the same as  [Passing page URL parameter to controller in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013941/passing-page-url-parameter-to-controller-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing page URL parameter to controller in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013941/passing-page-url-parameter-to-controller-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: @ShahbazZafar nope

Comment: You got your answer solution or still looking for?

Answer (score 7):

web/routes.php

```
Route::get('/test/{id}','Controller@getname');
```

Controller file

```
public function getname(Request $request,$id)
{

    echo $id; # will output 4
    $param = $id;
    return view('test.test1')->with('param',$param);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the id in url as controller function parameters

```
public function something(Request $request,$id){
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: The first comma in the parameter list is not supposed to be there `public function something(Request $request, $id){
    return $id;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You should add extra parameters to your getName function.

```
# Stick to the convention of camelcase functions, not getname but getName
public function getName(Request $request, $param, $id)
{
    # This only works when you pass an id field while performing a POST request.
    # echo ($request->input('id'));
    echo $param; # will output 'test1'
    echo $id; # will output 4
    return view('test.test1', compact('$param','id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple, you can follow this code in your controller

```
$url = url()->current();
$url = str_replace("http://", "", $url);
dd($url);
```

output: localhost/test/test1/4